# Python tkinter - Functions

Tags: python, function, tkinter

...

```
def f():
   unosliste=Entry(prozor3)
   unosliste.place(x=450,y=600)
   gg=Button(prozor3, text='Ok')
   gg.place(x=560,y=600)
   s=unosliste.get()
   return
def aksz(event):
      s=s.split()
      ...
```

So, my question is..I want to work in a new function(aksz) with file 's' which was defined in previous function(I can do all that in one function), but I don't know how to get it, or translate it. Do you know how can I 'translate' file and work with it in other functions? It's Python tkinter I work for the first time so I'm not aware of many function tools there.
Thanks!

Comment: make sure that `unosliste` is either global, or an instance variable, and then put `s = unosliste.get()` in `aksz`.

Comment: the reason the `.get()` method exists is because you need to call it when you actually do stuff with the string content, if you call it immediately after creating the entry it returns an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change a variable defined in another function without it being an instance variable e.g. `self.variable` within a class or being a global variable e.g. `global variable`.

Answer (score 0):

just make s global and any external function will find it adding:

`def f():
   global s
   unosliste=Entry(prozor3)
   ...`